# "General" tab missing in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Today, I began using Visual Studio 2015 - Visual C++ in particular. When I ran my code (shown below), I noticed that the "General" tab in the output window was missing - meaning I could not see the output of my code. All the tabs i can see are Build, Build Order, and Debug - that's it. Anyone know what is going on? Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I assume that the console output window is disappearing fast before you got chance to look the output. Keep a break point before the return statement and execute the program.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the Output window: Menu View - Output (Alt+2) or search 'Output` in the Quick Launch (in the window Frame next to minimize, restore, close buttons)